# Python dataframe sql server parameter syntax

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I want to insert the contents of a dataframe which has 3 columns and 50 rows into a MS SQL Server table. So far i can simply insert values (as you can see in the code below). 
Kindly suggest how I can easily insert my dataframe, while avoiding

> pyodbc.IntegrityError: 23000.

Code:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into OutputTable(ID, Fruit, DateTime) 
                  values (2954685,'Pineapple','2014-07-17 15:44:53.620')""")
cnn_out.commit()
```

Comment: If the error is:

IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Cannot insert
explicit value for identity column in table 'TABLENAME' when
IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. (544) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Then I would guess set IDENTITY_INSERT to on?

Comment: The integrity error is secondary but thanks for shedding some light on it. How can I insert a dataframe with 3 columns and 50 rows into the the table i described in the question. How do I modify the cursor.execute statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to convert the dataframe to a tuple, then use the following construction:

data = [tuple(x) for x in results_out.values]

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO ShopperOutput values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
cnn_out.commit()
```

The question marks represent the number of columns in the output table.